# django get path to previous parent directory on template tag

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

i want to extends from an base.html that is before(previous?) the parent directory.

the path estructure is this:

templates:

- base

  - base.html <--- file i want to extends.
- pages

  - general

    - home.html <--- file from where i got the error

the problem is

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /
> pages/general/base/base.html

and here is the html code from home.thml in template/pages/general/base.html
for call .base.html

```
{% extends "../base/base.html" %}
```

i dont know how i can go to the previous folder from parent directory, and i dont even know how to find documentation referenced to that, im not native english speaker so its hard to find and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tow dots

```
../
```

takes you to the priv dir so that will make you at the pages dir

```
../..
```

will take you to the parent of the pages dir
so your import should be like :

```
{% extends "../../base/base.html" %}
```

Comment: thanks you a lot, idk how i cant find or figure out before.